# Image of continous function in R

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be injective and continuous. Prove that

- $f$ is monotonic.
- The image of $f$ is $(c,d)$ or maybe ($-\infty,+\infty$).

I proved $f$ is monotonic but I don't know how to the second proposition begin.

Thankyou so much.

Comment: You can use the fact that it's monotonic to demonstrate the second proposition.

Comment: If the image were closed (or half-closed), then that would suggest that the function achieved a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: It may also be $(-\infty,d) $ or $(c,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $c = \mbox{inf Im} f$ and $d = \mbox{sup Im} f$. If $c<y<d$, then $c\leq c'<y<d'\leq d$ for some $c',\ d'\in\mbox{Im} f$. By the intermediate value theorem $y\in \mbox{Im} f$. We use the fact  that $f$ is monotonic to prove that $c,\ d \not\in \mbox{Im} f$.

Comment: Thank you, i proved it by following your hint

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $f$ is monotonic increasing function (Consider $-f$ otherwise). Let $$c:=\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)\in\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty\}$$
$$d:=\lim_{x\to b-}f(x)\in\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$$
Note that these limits exist because of monotonicity of $f$. Now, $f$ takes every value in $(c,d)$ by intermediate value theorem. Also any other value is not attained by $f$ by monotonicity and we are done.

Comment: Thank you, i proved it by following your hint